# Headphone jack resets in ALSA when unplugged. 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04, alsa, headphones

I have been able to get my headphones to work using the alsa mixer, but it resets whenever the headphones are unplugged or the computer is rebooted. I never had this problem with previous versions, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Computer is an HP Pavilion dv7 with beats audio (though, I doubt that maters with linux). Intel Soundcard. Running Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Any help would be appreciated. I've only been using Ubuntu for a few months, so I'm no expert.